# Objective-C handling multiple gestures at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

For a project I am working on I need a view to be able to handle two UIGestureRecognizers at one time: UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer. Specifically, the user should be able to press and hold the view for a new view to appear that disappears upon release (I already have this working). Then, when the user taps the view while holding it (i.e. with another finger), an action should occur (I cannot figure out how to get this working). A similar type example would be Snapchat stories: Press and hold to view the first image/video of a story, then tap to move to the next image/video.

I tried setting the following method to return YES:

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

But this method only allows multiple gestures to be added to a view, and does not allow for them to be handled at the same time.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: touchesBegan and touchesEnded?

Comment: Can't use use those instead of gesture recognizers? It's fairly easy to implement the functionality you explained with those, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue. I had the exclusiveTouch property on the view set to YES. When I removed that line of code, having both gesture recognizers together worked great!